# coreplot busy x axis

Tags: xcode, core-plot

Is there a way to limit the number of labels across the x-axis when there is too much data and the x-axis gets very crowded? I have tried manually counting and deleting labels but it doesn't work.
thanks.

Comment: It depends on the labeling policy. Which one are you using?

Comment: Where would I find the labeling policy?

Comment: The labeling policy is an axis property. The default policy creates tick marks and labels one unit apart. You can keep the constant spacing and change the distance between ticks, divide the axis length into a certain number of equal divisions, automatically choose "nice" divisions, or provide your own list of custom locations. Look up the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicy` enum.

Answer (score 0):

The labeling policy is an axis property. The default policy creates tick marks and labels one unit apart. You can keep the constant spacing and change the distance between ticks, divide the axis length into a certain number of equal divisions, automatically choose "nice" divisions, or provide your own list of custom locations. Look up the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicy` enum.

Comment: this is not working for me. I tried all of the options I can find. My issue is that when I have over about 75 items to plot the x labels all overlap I can't read any o them. Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you've tried and offer additional suggestions.